# How to make prediction based on a set of rules in R

Tags: r, key, rule

I have a list containing a set of rules (or keys or dictionaries; whatever you'd call it).

```
    > list.prob[c(1,2)]
[[1]]

x           no        yes

  overcast 0.07692308 0.42857143

  rainy    0.38461538 0.33333333

  sunny    0.53846154 0.23809524
```

Therefore, the value for overcast given "no" is -0.08 and given "yes" is 0.43.

```
[[2]]
      y

x             no       yes

  cool 0.2307692 0.3333333

  hot  0.3846154 0.2380952

  mild 0.3846154 0.4285714
```

By the same token, the value for hot given "no" is 0.38 and given "yes" is 0.24.

Once the rules are established, I have a matrix of characters

```
    > mat[c(1:4),]

   outlook    temperature humidity windy

[1,] "sunny"    "hot"       "high"   "no" 

[2,] "sunny"    "hot"       "high"   "yes"

[3,] "overcast" "hot"       "high"   "no" 

[4,] "rainy"    "mild"      "high"   "no"
```

The question is given "no" or "yes", how can I use the prior rules and convert cells in the matrix (stored as characters) into their corresponding numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want? I wasn't sure where the yes / no came into play, so I've just looked up the probability of "yes".

```
a  <- matrix(runif(6), nrow = 3)
weather <- c("sunny", "rainy", "overcast")
temp <- c("cool", "hot", "mild")
yn <- c("yes", "no")
rownames(a) <- weather
colnames(a) <- yn
b  <- matrix(runif(6), nrow = 3)
rownames(b) <- temp
colnames(b) <- yn
c <- data.frame(weather = sample(weather, 10, replace = T), 
     temp = sample(temp, 10, replace = T))
d <- data.frame(weather = a[c$weather, "yes"], temp = b[c$temp, "yes"])
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not reproducible, so I tried to make it so:

```
list.prob <-
list(structure(c(0.07692308, 0.38461538, 0.53846154, 0.42857143, 
0.33333333, 0.23809524), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    x = c("overcast", "rainy", "sunny"), y = c("no", "yes")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"))), structure(c(0.2307692, 0.3846154, 0.3846154, 0.3333333, 
0.2380952, 0.4285714), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    x = c("cool", "hot", "mild"), y = c("no", "yes")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"))))
mat <-
structure(c("sunny", "sunny", "overcast", "rainy", "hot", "hot", 
"hot", "mild"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("outlook", 
"temperature")))
```

which gives something very much like what you started with (except limited `mat` to only those columns that seemed to correspond to entries in `list.prob`:

```
> list.prob
[[1]]
          y
x                  no       yes
  overcast 0.07692308 0.4285714
  rainy    0.38461538 0.3333333
  sunny    0.53846154 0.2380952

[[2]]
      y
x             no       yes
  cool 0.2307692 0.3333333
  hot  0.3846154 0.2380952
  mild 0.3846154 0.4285714

> mat
     outlook    temperature
[1,] "sunny"    "hot"      
[2,] "sunny"    "hot"      
[3,] "overcast" "hot"      
[4,] "rainy"    "mild"
```

Your problem is then to translate each column in `mat` based on a table in `list.prob`, but which column is used is conditional on the value of another variable (which I'll call `yesorno`).

```
# setup
res <- matrix(0,nrow=nrow(mat),ncol=ncol(mat))
yesorno <- "yes"
# actual computation
for (col in seq_len(ncol(mat))) {
  res[,col] <- list.prob[[col]][,yesorno][mat[,col]]
}
```

giving

```
> res
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.2380952 0.2380952
[2,] 0.2380952 0.2380952
[3,] 0.4285714 0.2380952
[4,] 0.3333333 0.4285714
```

This assumes the first column of `mat` corresponds to the first element of `list.prob`, etc.; if the mapping isn't so simple, then you need some way of relating them (perhaps naming the elements of `list.prob` according to the column names of `mat` and looping over the column names to do the lookup in `list.prob`).